# VS Multi Project template creates an extra folder when creating new project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-templates

I Created a Multi-Project custom template. Here is my folder structure after I Exported the Template.

```
ServiceTemplate
 |_Template.Service
  |_MyTemplate.vstemplate
 |_Template.Service.Interface
  |_MyTemplate.vstemplate
 |_root.vstemplate
```

I zipped all files and folders under "ServiceTemplate" which Gave me "ServiceTemplate.zip"

I copied that zip file under "Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates"

I went to visual studio and created a new project (Test.Service) from my Template and solution (TestService).

I ticked "Create solution folder" when creating a new project but didn't work

I added false in root.vstemplate but didn't work

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">  
  <TemplateData>  
    <Name>Service Template</Name>  
    <Description></Description>  
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType> 
    <CreateNewFolder>false</CreateNewFolder>  
  </TemplateData>  
  <TemplateContent>  
    <ProjectCollection>  
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$" CopyParameters="true">  
          Template.Service\MyTemplate.vstemplate  
        </ProjectTemplateLink>

        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Interface" CopyParameters="true">  
          Template.Service.Interface\MyTemplate.vstemplate  
        </ProjectTemplateLink>  
    </ProjectCollection>  
  </TemplateContent>  
</VSTemplate>
```

*Expected*

```
TestService
 |_packages
 |_TestService.sln
 |_Test.Service
  |_Test.Service.csproj
 |_Test.Service.Interface
  |_Test.Service.Interface.csproj
```

*Actual*

```
TestService
 |_packages
 |_TestService.sln
 |_TestService <--- (un-necessary folder)
  |_Test.Service
   |_Test.Service.csproj
  |_Test.Service.Interface
   |_Test.Service.Interface.csproj
```

Comment: *"I ticked "Create solution folder" when creating a new project"* did you try creating the project the other way? Checking that box is what causes the solution to be created in its own folder above the project in normal cases.

Comment: @Herohtar I did Create without ticking that box but still the problem persists.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but was using vs2022 and dotnet new templates. My solution was to tick
"Place solution and project in the same directory"
I always ignored this checkbox as I have multiple projects and never want solution files in the same directory, but the option is misleading. When I tick that box all that happens is the extra folder is gone.